# Use multiple constrictors of one class to store data in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, constructor

I have a class say `User` with properties `name`,`age`,`nationality`,`eyeColor`
and I have three constructors.

1. The required empty constructor for Firebase,
2. User(name, nationality),
3. User(name, nationality, age, eyeColor).

Anytime I try to save data in Firebase with constructor 2, I find that the data is actually saved with constructor 3 with `age` and `eyeColor` being `0` and `null` respectively.

How do I save data with only the parameters of constructor 2 without creating a new class for constructor 3?

Comment: Nice and clear question! Welcome to Stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have those properties not to be displayed at all in your database because when you are creating an object of your `User` class, those fields will get the default values, `0` and `null`.

If you want to make sure that you'll never have such values in your database, then you can use a `Map` to write data and populate only the fields that you need.

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", name);
map.put("nationality", nationality);
userRef.setValue(map);
```

So this will solve your issue but without creating an object of the class.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never used the Map object before but I just saw it in the documentation. Your example is very useful.
But then if I want to retrieve this data, I can I convert the JSON into the class object using `.getValue(User.class)` without having issues?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can, if the name of the properties have the exact same name with name of the properties from your `User` class. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yup! Worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem. I have not faced this kind of situation before. However, after reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data), which says,

> First, create a database reference to your user data. Then use set() /
>   setValue() to save a user object to the database with the user's
>   username, full name, and birthday. You can pass set a string, number,
>   boolean, null, array or any JSON object. **Passing null will remove
>   the data at the specified location.**

I would like to recommend to construct your second constructor like this.

```
public User(String name, String nationality) {
    this.name = name;  
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.age = null;
    this.eyeColor = null;
}
```

I hope this will not save the added information in a user key. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I tried this even before I asked.
Setting those properties to null on initial creation will create a database entry setting the property with a value = null too, so the property will still be there with a value of null (or any other default value).
It is when the value is there already and you want to delete it that passing null will delete it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a constructor that leaves `age` and `eyeColor` set to `null`

```
User(name, nationality, age, eyeColor) {
    this(name, nationality); //age and eyeColor will have the default value - null
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but setting any values to null for any property will make Firebase to save that property with its value = null in the database.
What I want to achieve is not seeing that property at all in that part of the database.
Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

0 and null are the default values for number and object members for all objects throughout the JVM.  When you create a new object, if you don't assign a value to members, they will get the default values.  If you don't want the default values, find some other value to assign.

Comment: Wow! This is Doug Stevenson replying to my question. Jeez!
I read your articles on using architecture components with Firebase, but I noticed that my retrieved data was appearing twice on my logcat. I dunno why.

Anyways, on this issue, I don't want to assign any default values to that constructor. I want to see only that constructor's properties in that path of my database and nothing else.

Thank you!

Comment: OK, so, what you're trying to do isn't possible.  See my other answer.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I've seen it

Answer (score 0):

In Java `String` default value is `null` and `int` default value is `0` .when you call `constructor`, all properties get `initialize` with default `values` .now when you call 2nd `constructor`, though your are filling two property (name, nationality) but other two are getting `initialize` to default value .

Hence you should write logic either while saving(could be if condition) or `assign` desired values in `constructor` .

Answer (score 0):

You can't be selective about which properties of a JavaBean object make it into the database.  The SDK will always use all of the properties all of the time, regardless of their values.  It will only exclude properties whose fields or accessors are annotated with @Exclude.

If you want to be selective about which values make it into the database, you'll have to construct a Map and put the values into that to store in the database, using whatever logic to decide which values are appropriate.

In other words, you can't simply depend on the constructor of a JavaBean type object to determine which values to include or exclude from that object.  You have to write special code to make these decisions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm checking the Firebase documentation on using Map right now